# Why can't we find the specific values of a [n] and s [n] when n takes a definite positive integer value?

Tags: differential-equations

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a[n_ /; n > 1] := a[1] + (n - 1) d; 
s[n_] := 
 n (a[1] + a[n])/2; eqn = {s[6] == 90, a[7]^2 == a[3] a[9], 
  d != 0}; var = First@Solve[eqn, {a[1], d}]
a[1] + (n - 1) d /. var // FullSimplify
a[n_] := %
n a[1] + n (n - 1)/2 d /. var // Simplify
s[n_] := %
```

After calculating the general term formula a [n] and the sum formula s [n] above, why cannot the specific values of a [n] and s [n] be calculated when n takes a certain positive integer?

for example:

```
a[2]==d + Null

s[9]==d + Null
```

How can I obtain accurate values?

[image]

Comment: Have you forgotten some `;` in front of your line shifts....? `Null` is the output of `;`

Comment: I have provided an example of answer which you can use. Now, _please_ do not go blindly adding some other code making it not work again, and then posting a new question with a slightly different needs. Try to _understand_ what is going on and how problems are solved in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use [`SetDelayed (:=)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) together with [`Out (%)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html) because `Out` will be reevaluated every time you call for `a`, and will therefore not refer to what you actually want. Also, you are defining `a` and `s` twice with different meaning, which is not a good practice. You should wrap the calculation of `var` in a `Module` so that definitions `a` and `s` used for solving the problem are localized.

```
var = Module[{a, s},
   a[n_ /; n > 1] := a[1] + (n - 1) d;
   s[n_] := n (a[1] + a[n])/2; 
   eqn = {s[6] == 90, a[7]^2 == a[3] a[9], d != 0}; 
   First@Solve[eqn, {a[1], d}]
   ];

a[n_ /; n > 1] := a[1] + (n - 1) d /. var // FullSimplify
s[n_] := n a[1] + n (n - 1)/2 d /. var // Simplify

a[5]
(* -8 + a[1] *)

s[5]
(* 5 (-4 + a[1]) *)
```